# Ping network and get mac addres

Tags: c++, ping, mac-address

I'm a starting C/C++ programmer.

What I want is the following thing:

Start program, starts to ping whole network and saves the addresses that where active. When done, get mac address from ip addresses that where stored before, and save them.

When done, loop trough the mac address list, and find 1 mac adress, when found, shout around that he found it.

Something like that does I want to make.

I've Googled a lot, but nothing realy helped me.

So my question, what do I need (which libraries, which statements), so I can program this.

On note, my OS is at the moment Windows, but I want to make it compatible with Linux in the future also.

Comment: my tip would be to check out [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/libs/asio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `arp` tool on the commandline eg `arp -a 192.168.0.100`

From c++ it depends on your OS, on Windows it's [SendArp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

To scan for all machines on the lan use `nmap` - see [How do I get a list of the active IP-addresses, MAC-addresses and NetBIOS names on the LAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90755/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-active-ip-addresses-mac-addresses-and-netbios-names)

Comment: it's a start, but first i need to ping the whole network and find the actifs one (and fast, not waiting 8 seconds for every host that he can't find

Comment: @TWCrap: You can't reliably determine what devices are on a network if you are not willing to wait for their replies.

Comment: @TWCrap, you can change the timeout for ping/arp if you know how quickly the machines will respond. A better way to scan all the machines is nmap http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90755/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-active-ip-addresses-mac-addresses-and-netbios-names but you still have to wait for them

Comment: @dreamlax: i know, but cant i send 2 pings instead of the standard of 4, and can i send them to more ip's at once. (so first attemt, ing *.*.*.1 / 10, seccond 11 / 20.....

Comment: @MartinBeckett: i tried nmap in my own command line, but it said that he didn't recognice the command...