# How to get all ip address in LAN?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting all system name connected in LAN network. I don't know how to get IP Address of all system name like (192.168.1.15).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IP of all hosts in LAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042789/how-to-get-ip-of-all-hosts-in-lan)

Comment: …or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803073/get-local-ip-address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a list of the active IP-addresses, MAC-addresses and NetBIOS names on the LAN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90755/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-active-ip-addresses-mac-addresses-and-netbios-names)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
foreach(NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
    {
        if(!ip.IsDnsEligible)
        {
            if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
                // All IP Address in the LAN
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Only drawback of this code is that the information returned by instances of `UnicastIPAddressInformation` is not available for operating systems earlier than Windows XP.

Comment: Thnq..in comment all ip address in lan how can i get that in richtextbox..Kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the hostnames (as your question implies), you can use the `Dns.GetHostAddresses` method to translate them to IP addresses.